# Importando dados EXCEL para PHP!

Tags: php, microsoft-excel

Olá, venho pedir uma ajuda em relação a EXCEL e PHP;
A pouco tempo entrei em uma empresa, onde tem um dashboard feito em VBA em EXCEL, porém, percebi que ele da muito problema. Então resolvi desenvolver um novo dashboard, retirar do VBA e ir para o Browser(HTML5, PHP e Mysql pois tem sistema de login e senha).

O dashboard no excel faz o seguinte:

- Ao aperta a seta verde ele começa a fazer suas funções
- Com a extensão do SELENIUM, ele acessa automaticamente o site, faz o dowload das planilhas em Excel e coloca os valores no dashboard
- A cada 4 minutos ele deleta tudo que está na pasta dowload(onde os arquivos são baixados) e faz esse procedimento todo de novo, sempre atualizando os dados;

Aqui está a imagem do dashboard: https://prnt.sc/fhdemt

Ele imprime os valores na tela tudo bonitinho, sobe a barrinha ali onde está o "Planejado x Produzido", calcula a porcentagem, etc...

Eu quero migrar tudo isso pro Browser, pra PHP. Quero que ele faça o mesmo dessas funcionalidades dele. Mas como?! Como fazer o PHP também acessar o site automaticamente, fazer o dowload e jogar tudo na tela?

**OBS: Vou utilizar o mesmo modelo do dashboard do excel, no browser...**
Salvo a imagem em PNG e coloco no browser e depois jogo as informações em cima? Ou faço o mesmo dashboard do 0?

Agradeço de coração a quem me ajudar!!! Estou pegando muito fragmentos de códigos desse tipo na internet, mas nada concreto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foram várias dúvidas em apenas uma única pergunta, então vamos por parte:

1. Você deverá desenvolver um *dashboard* do zero, assim será mais fácil prestar manutenção futuramente.
2. Sobre acessar o arquivo do site, você pode fazer uma cópia dele para o `/tmp` do seu projeto, usando o método [Copy](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.copy.php). Assim, caso necessite manipular o arquivo novamente não precisará realizar uma nova requisição ao site. Segue um exemplo usando `Copy`:

   ```
   $url = "http://site.com/arquivos/nome.csv";
   if (copy($url, '/tmp/' . urldecode(basename($url)))) {
       echo 'Arquivo copiado com sucesso!';
   } else {
       echo 'Erro ao copiar arquivo!';
   }
   ```
3. Para manipular arquivos `.csv` no php, segue uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/216512/como-manipular-excel-com-php?answertab=oldest#tab-top) no Stack sobre o assunto;
4. Para manipular as informações no [html](https://github.com/thephpleague/csv/blob/8.x/examples/extract.php). Não é a melhor forma, mas como você está no início, já ajuda;

Acredito que respondi todas as informações que havia descrito. Caso tenha mais dúvidas, divida em perguntas no Stack. Quando mais descrição melhor será ajuda.

Comment: O site tem login e senha. Como faço pra por pra ele mesmo colocar o login e senha e apertar o botão?

Comment: selenium.Start "chrome", "about:blank"
selenium.Window.SetPosition 0, -1100
On Error GoTo Erro
selenium.Get "https://siteaqui/"
selenium.FindElementById("user_login").SendKeys cUsername
selenium.FindElementById("user_password").SendKeys cPassword
selenium.FindElementById("sign_in_button").Click

Em VBA eu uso assim.

Comment: @AlexandreAmado sua pergunta refere-se sobre excel e php, mas seu comentário é contendo o erro é sobre [selenium](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started+with+Selenium+for+Automated+Website+Testing#GettingStartedwithSeleniumforAutomatedWebsiteTesting-IntroducingSelenium). Eu não tenho o conhecimento necessário para te ajudar referente automatização de interação web. Recomendo que crie um novo post para que entendedores do assunto possam te ajudar.

Comment: Não, foi apenas um exemplo @DjalmaManfrin. Eu quero saber como eu faço pra ele automaticamente colocar login e senha, acessar o site e fazer o download. Ai em cima você ensinou apenas como entrar no site e baixar, mas o site que quero acessar pede login e senha( eu tenho o login e senha ).

Comment: Sabe me dizer se o servidor é ftp?

Comment: Esse é o site: https://packmanager.nulogy.net/sign_in

Comment: Entre em contato com o suporte da hospedagem e veja se elem trabalham com ftp

Comment: Estou longe da empresa nesse momento, mas deixei uma mensagem pro Gestor de produção. Pra que será necessário saber se é FTP?! Pode apenas me dizer o código pra eu ter uma base de como seria esse acesso? Pra eu testar aqui, em vez de esperar a resposta do Gestor.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, você pode fazer isso via PHP também.

Você precisará fazer o download do arquivo usando a função file_get_contents() do PHP.

Precisará usar uma biblioteca para ler o conteúdo dos arquivos Excel, como por exemplo:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/

Ou então:
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Eu sugiro que você crie o dashboard do zero com HTML e CSS ao invés de gerar uma imagem e sobrepor os dados.

Comment: Agradeço pela informação Diego! Abraços