# Como manipular EXCEL com PHP?

Tags: php, microsoft-excel

Como faço para manipular células do excel com PHP?

Por exemplo: Preciso pegar 2 células, em linhas distintas
Célula 1: AB2
Célula 2: BC4

E multiplicá-las AB2 * BC4 = ?

E imprimir na tela esse valor. Tudo isso em PHP, mas como?

*Tipo de arquivo: CSV*

**Caso não souberem como, tenho outra questão:
E se salvar as planilhas CSV no Banco de dados e manipular também com PHP? Tem  como?! Dá mesmo exemplo que a de cima...**

Comment: o formato CSV não é exclusivo do EXCEL, ele é um formato texto tabular e com um padrão de separação das colunas. Por exemplo a forma mais comum é circundar o valor da coluna com aspas " e separar as colunas com ponto e vírgula ; Se você abrir um arquivo CSV no editor de textos verá o que estou falando e possívelmente entenderá que a sua solução é pegar a coluna na posição que você quer e somar o valor, mas lendo uma linha de um arquivo texto e não de um formato EXCEL

Comment: Beleza. Sei que não é exclusivo, mas só falei que estou usando o csv vindo do excel. E quero saber como manipular COM PHP.

Comment: Vocẽ poderia usar p [PHPExecel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel), se for o seu problema. Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando eu necessito utilizar `.csv` no php eu utilizo a biblioteca [csv.thephpleague.com](http://csv.thephpleague.com/8.0/). Você pode [instalar](http://gilbertoalbino.com/instalacao-do-composer-no-ubuntu/) via [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/). Contém exemplos bem didáticos que podem te ajudar.

Desta forma você pode trabalhar célula por célula e introduzir em uma tabela:

```
<?php
    use League\Csv\Reader;
    require '../vendor/autoload.php';

    $inputCsv = Reader::createFromPath('caminho/arquivo.csv');
    $inputCsv->setDelimiter(';');

    //captura o cabeçalho do arquivo
    $headers = $inputCsv->fetchOne(0);

    //Retorna no máximo 25 linhas, começando pela linha 801
    $res = $inputCsv->setOffset(800)->setLimit(25)->fetch();
?>
```

Neste [link](https://github.com/thephpleague/csv/blob/8.x/examples/extract.php) há um exemplo prático, espero que te ajude: