# Como recuperar dados de um form html e enviar para um arquivo MS Excel?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Preciso recuperar dados de um formulario do HTML e enviar para um arquivo de Excel, existe alguma forma com JavaScript ou com PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma forma respondida num post do StackOverflow em inglês. Você pode adaptar o código de acordo com o que você quer. Segue o link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704449/export-html-form-data-to-excel

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Para manipular arquivos do Excel no PHP eu trabalho com a biblioteca [csv](http://csv.thephpleague.com/8.0/). Para instalar o pacote você precisará usar o [composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

Para criar um arquivo com esta biblioteca é muito fácil.

**Crie um header**

```
$header = ["nome" , "email", "contato", "messagem", "empresa"];
```

**Seus Dados**

```
$contents = [
    ['Fulano da Silva', "fulano.silva@...", 9999999999, 'Texto', StackOverflow],
    ['Ciclano da Silva', "ciclano.silva@...", 9999999999, 'Texto', StackOverflow]
];
```

**Chamando a biblioteca**

```
$writer = Writer::createFromFileObject(new SplTempFileObject());
//Criando um arquivo CSV temporário

$writer->setDelimiter("\t"); //Caracter delimitador
$writer->setNewline("\r\n"); //Forma do windows aplicar o quebra-linha
$writer->setOutputBOM(Writer::BOM_UTF8);
//Saída das informações respeitando os caráteres especiais

$writer->insertOne($header);
$writer->insertAll($contents);
```

Caso queira fazer o download do arquivo adicione as linhas

```
$writer->setEncodingFrom('ISO-8859-15');
$writer->output('firstname.csv');
```

Maiores informações

- [Manipulando CSV](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/216512/como-manipular-excel-com-php/216539#216539)
- [Exemplos](https://github.com/thephpleague/csv/tree/8.x/examples)