# foreach - Percorrendo arquivo CSV

Tags: php, microsoft-excel, csv

Preciso percorrer um arquivo CSV para capturar um valor e imprimi-lo na tela.

Exemplo:

Coluna "N" linha "2", no caso, é a célula N2 que está escrito: 2,98

Como imprimir essa célula N2 na tela? Como chegar até lá?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?php
$h = fopen("produtividade do trabalho.csv","r");
$i = fgetcsv($h, null, ",");
foreach ($i as $indice => $valor) {
  echo var_dump($i);
}
?>
```

No código acima ele imprime isso para mim:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(278) "trabalho;"Código do projeto";"Código do item";"Data de início do trabalho real";"Data final do trabalho real";"Nome da linha";"Desempenho";"Disponibilidade";"Eficiência da linha";"Unidades produzidas";"Unidades previstas";"Unidade de medida";"Unidades padrão por hora";"Duração"" }
```

Que no caso, é tudo que está na linha 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa abrir o csv e percorrer em array.

Veja esse exemplo removido do próprio site do PHP com uma leve alterada:

```
    $row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("csv.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    //Passagem pelas linhas
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        // Passagem pelas colunas
        for ($col = 0; $col < $num; $col++)
        {
            //Printando apenas a coluna 14
            if ($col == 14)
            {
                echo 'Exibindo valor para linha:'.$row.' e para a coluna: '.$data[$col] . "<br />\n";
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Perfeito! Era o que eu precisava! Muito obrigado, estava a muito tempo procurando isso, haha. Agora vou dar uma atualizada e implementar no meu código. Agradeço!

Comment: E tipo, ali no col == 14 ele percorre e vai até a letra N, certo. Agora, se eu quiser pegar apenas a linha 2? E não o "N" todo. Porque neste perfeito exemplo, ele me da tudo que tem na N. E eu preciso pegar apenas a linha 2

Comment: Você precisa fazer a comparação com o '$row' tbm, if($row == 2){ //bloco }

Comment: Muito obrigado novamente!

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso, o problema está na chamada da função fgetcsv. O terceiro parâmetro é o delimitador, que você está passando a virgula (,), mas segundo seu exemplo, este csv está separado por ponto-e-virgula (;).

Portanto para corrigir, basta trocar a virgula pelo ponto-e-virgula :)

```
$i = fgetcsv($h, null, ";");
```

Documentação oficial do fgetcsv: [php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fgetcsv.php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fgetcsv.php)

Para pegar a coluna N, basta recuperar dentro do foreach a posição 13 da variável $valor: $valor[13]

Comment: Obrigado Diego, não tinha reparado!
 Mas o meu problema ainda está no ar, que é pegar uma célula específica. Esse ai está pegando tudo da Linha 1, mas eu quero pegar da Coluna N da linha 2

Comment: @Alex_Alex_Alex Neste caso, dentro do foreach, a variável $valor deverá ser um array com as colunas, portanto para pegar a coluna N, é só contar o índice do Array equivalente a esta coluna. Ex: A = 0, B = 1, C = 2, etc. Neste caso a N deve ser a posição 13, podendo pegar o valor assim: $valor[13]

Answer (score 1):

A manipulação de arquivos `.csv` pode ser feita facilmente. Há um pacote chamado CSV que você pode [instalar via `composer`](https://getcomposer.org/download/). Recentemente publiquei [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/216512/como-manipular-excel-com-php/216539#216539) sobre este problema.

Este pacote transforma as informações do arquivo em um `array` que pode ser facilmente percorrido.

```
<?php
    use League\Csv\Reader;
    require '../vendor/autoload.php';

    $csv = Reader::createFromPath('caminho/arquivo.csv');
    $csv->setDelimiter(';');

    //remove da busca o cabeçalho do arquivo
    $headers = $csv->fetchOne(0);

    //Retorna todos os resultados
    $linhas = $csv->fetchAll();

    //Retorna o valor
    $valor = $linhas[0][13];
?>
```

As linhas e as colunas começam com o índice 0.

Comment: $inputCsv->fetchAll(); não deveria ser $csv->fetchAll(); ?

Comment: Concordo.  Este é um exemplo do próprio pacote. Apenas alterei para `csv` para ficar mais explícito. Agradeço por comentar.